Was the al-Arouri apartment hit with six GBU 39 bombs, two of which didn't explode?
Lebanese LBCI media claims in an "exclusive" from Jan 2024:

In an operation displaying remarkable precision, Israel targeted the apartment of the Deputy Head of the Political Bureau of Hamas, Saleh al-Arouri, along with six of his associates in the southern suburbs of Beirut. [...]
The apartment was targeted with six missiles, four of which detonated, while two remained unexploded, as seen in images obtained by LBCI.
The missiles used belong to the GBU 39-B category, precise and guided munitions, each weighing 129 kilograms. The size of these missiles supports the notion that they were launched by fighter jets, not drones.

But the media report itself doesn't seem to include said images of two unexploded GBU 39's in the apartment. Also, it seems like a lot of bombs for one apartment.

AFAICT the 6-bombs claim is due to 6 holes in the roof; see 2nd image here: https://www.reddit.com/r/2ndYomKippurWar/comments/18z1qv0/images_show_saleh_alarouri_was_assassinated_with/ But I'm skeptical those are bomb entry holes. They are pretty small.
